# Write a program that uses a Stack to check parentheses (balanced and correct nesting)

Tags: python, stack

The parentheses are: (), [] and {}. I'm a beginner and so am fairly new to this all.

```
print(check_parentheses("()"))
print(check_parentheses("(()())"))
print(not check_parentheses("(()))"))  # Unbalanced
print(not check_parentheses("((())"))  # Unbalanced
print(check_parentheses("({})")) #fick fel här
print(not check_parentheses("({)}"))  # Bad nesting
print(check_parentheses("({} [()] ({}))"))
print(not check_parentheses("({} [() ({)})"))  # Unbalanced and bad nesting
```

All of these should print True.

All I've managed to do thus far is write a bunch of if-statements where ,for example, if character is == "(" then number_of_left_parentheses += 1.

I do realize that this is suboptimal since it forces me into writing an if-elif-statement for all 6 possible parentheses, which makes my code longer than it has to be.

Anyone that could help me solve this problem using Stacks?

Comment: When you see an opening "bracket" then push it to the stack. When you see a closing "bracket" pop the stack. If the popped element is not the corresponding opening "bracket" then there's a mismatch. When the input ends, and the stack isn't empty, there's a mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Stacks is a simple data structure, where you can either add or remove an element in a last-in first-out manner. Think of a stack as a pile of plates. You can always add another plate at the top, or remove the top plate.

There are several ways to implement a stack in python. For instance, lists can be used as a stack. Examining the [documentation for lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), there are in particular two methods .append(x) and .pop(). Append adds an item **x** to the end of the list, and pop removes the last item.

In this case you will use the stack to keep track of the open parenthesis, and implement logic to handle the different cases for open and closed parenthesis.

Comment: I've managed to make all True except for print(not check_parentheses("({)}")) . def check_parentheses(string):
    open_parentheses = "{(["
    closed_parentheses = "})]"
    stack1 = Stack()
    for char in string:
        if char in open_parentheses:
            stack1.push(char)
    for char in string:
        if char in closed_parentheses and stack1.get_size() > 0:
            stack1.pop()
        elif char in closed_parentheses and stack1.get_size() == 0:
            return False

    if(stack1.is_empty()):
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: Nice! I think you need to account for whether the removed closing parenthesis is matching the top of the stack. I.e., you need to check whether the returned parenthesis from stack1.pop() matches char